# Enumerating the align environment

Tags: align, enumerate

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{42}

\begin{align}
                 a & = b + c              \label{label1} \\
    \alpha_{i,j,k} & = \theta^2 + \phi^2  \label{label2} \\
      M_\text{res} & = a + \alpha_{i,j,k} \label{label3}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

How can I enumerate the three equations? Wrapping the `align` environment in an `enumerate` environment and starting each equation line with `\item` won't work.

The equations should be enumerated like normal, and will thus depend on what comes before the `align` environment in question. I've arbitrarily set the equation counter to 42 to represent the content before the `align`. I also need to reference the equation labels as normal.

Comment: Don't they have already a number?

Comment: @egreg: They do have automatic numbering, which depends on what comes before the `align` environment. I need to enumerate the three equations as 1., 2. and 3. on the left hand side.

Comment: What's the reason? I see none.

Comment: @egreg: I'm outlining the mathematical steps of numerical algorithms.

Comment: Do you need to refer to those numbers?

Comment: @egreg: I need to be able to refer to the equations as normal (`\eqref`), but the enumerations only list the steps in the algorithm.

Comment: It seems sufficient to use a regular `enumerate` then with `\item $a = b + c$ \label{label1}`...

Comment: @Werner: This doesn't typeset the equations as equations, excludes the equation number and the equations will no longer be aligned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `alignat` and a `\step` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{step}
\newcommand{\step}{\stepcounter{step}\thestep.\quad}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{42}

\setcounter{step}{0} % do this when you want to reset the numbering
\begin{alignat}{2}
\step&&              a & = b + c              \label{label1} \\
\step&& \alpha_{i,j,k} & = \theta^2 + \phi^2  \label{label2} \\
\step&&   M_\text{res} & = a + \alpha_{i,j,k} \label{label3}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Surely there is a way to push the left number to the margin.

Comment: @John Kormylo: See my answer.

Comment: @egreg: Don't forget to reset the counter on entering of leaving the environment.

Comment: @Bernard Isn't `\setcounter{step}{0}` before the environment? `;-)`

Comment: @JohnKormylo That would be an abomination.

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution. Bernard's solution is indeed also worth checking out.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, it is. Didn't see it at the time, but I was doing a lot of things simultaneously…

Comment: @Bernard Well, maybe “abomination” is a tad excessive. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

A solution that uses the `flalign` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcounter{algostep}
\newcommand\step{\stepcounter{algostep}\hskip\parindent\thealgostep.}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{flalign}{\setcounter{algostep}{0}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{42}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
    \begin{flalign}
&\step & a & = b + c \label{label1} & \\
&\step & q & = e + f \label{label2} \\
&\step & z & = a + d \label{label3}
\end{flalign}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
\begin{flalign}
&\step & z & = a + d \label{label3} & \\
&\step & q & = e + f \label{label2} \\
&\step & a & = b + c \label{label1}
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution. This compiles nicely on its own, but sadly, somewhere in my main document, something is causing an error with `\gappto` when using your solution.

Comment: Could you produce a MWE so we can test?

Comment: I can't seem to pinpoint the error. It's none of the packages themselves, so there has to be something in my document causing the error.