# Itemized within align

Tags: align, enumerate, itemize, subequations

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass[12]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,amscd}
\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\text{\textbullet} && \eta_i & =  \beta_0+\beta_1 x_i^2 \label{mod:1} \\
\text{\textbullet} && \eta_i & =  \beta_0+\beta_1 \exp(x_i) \label{mod:2} \\
\text{\textbullet} && \eta_i & =  \beta_0+\beta_1 \sin(x_i) \label{mod:3}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

How can I itemize or enumerate the three equations in align?

I used \text{\textbullet}, but the bullets were not in the same place as itemize environments bullets.

I tried [Enumerating the align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199520/enumerating-the-align-environment), but again the numbering are in the middle of the line and are not the same as what I want.

I used subequations and align to lable them as (3.1a) ...

[image]

Comment: This confuses me. If this are three different items, there is no need to align them. If they are not three different items and all belong together, they should be just one item.

Comment: They are three different items. I wanted to label them as (3.1a), (3.1b), etc, so I used subequations and align.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `alignat`, and another with `flalign`. For the second solution, I define a `\mathitem command`, which emulates the layout of an itemize environment. I wouldn't recommend simulating `enumerate` as it would be redundant w.r.t. equation numbering.

```
\documentclass[12]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} \usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\mathitem{\makebox[\leftmargini][r]{\textbullet\hspace{\labelsep}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
  \begin{alignat}{2}
    \text{\textbullet} & \hspace{\labelsep} & \eta_i & = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i^2 \label{mod:1} \\
    \text{\textbullet} & & \eta_i & = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \exp(x_i) \label{mod:2} \\
    \text{\textbullet} & & \eta_i & = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \sin(x_i) \label{mod:3}
  \end{alignat}
\end{subequations}

\begin{subequations}
  \begin{flalign}
    \mathitem \eta_i & = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i^2 \label{mod:1} & & \\
    \mathitem \eta_i & = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \exp(x_i) \label{mod:2} \\
    \mathitem \eta_i & = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \sin(x_i) \label{mod:3}
  \end{flalign}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.
I agree with you with the numbering, but still my problem is that in this way the bullets are in the middle of the line, however the usual itemized environment for text starts at almost the beginning of the line with a small indent.

Comment: @Alirsd: I've updated my answer to include a layout more like want (hopefully).

Comment: Thank you so so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. Keep doing great. Thanks